# How to move a pawn to its location

Tags: c#, label, picturebox

I need to make a board game called "A game of goose" with c# in a form.

In this game, the player presses a button to roll a dice which creates a number.

I store the number that was created as int called 'totaal'. And everything combine as 'AllVariable.splaats1'. The pawn needs to be on the location corresponding to that number.

But what is the best/easiest way to move the pawn?

I was thinking to put Labels on the board and then when AllVariable.splaats1 = 5 that this would point to label5 and the pawn will move to the location of the Label.

[Click here the see an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbiOo.png)

I already tried this and with different approach but the pawn was in the corner.

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Name = "label" + AllVariable.splaats1;
frmkeuzespelers keuzespelers = new frmkeuzespelers();
picSpeler1.Location = lbl.Location;
```

Here I got a run time error: CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

```
Label lbl = "label" + AllVariable.splaats1;
picSpeler1.Location = lbl.Location;
```

Comment: the idea to modify the `Location` property of the figure is ok, but please a) that code does not compile, provide a minimal, verifyable example and b) "no success" is not a problem description we can work with. do you get a compiler error, runtime error, which? etc.

Comment: The example are multiple attempts. I will change this.

Comment: I separate the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Labels on the form called "label1" thru "labelX", you could do:

```
string lblName = "label" + AllVariable.splaats1.ToString();
Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(lblName, true);
if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Label)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)matches[0];
    picSpeler1.Location = lbl.Location;
}
```

> Thank you, it works just fine! Can you explain it a bit? – Kartercas

Explanation:

The variable "lblName" is simply a string that contains the name of the Label we are looking for (built from the literal value "label" concatenated with the Integer value in "AllVariable.splaats1").

We pass that string value representing the Label name to Controls.Find(), which will return an Array of Controls that have their name matching the value in "lblName".  The "true" value in the second parameter to that call means that it will search the form for matches including any nested containers, no matter how deep.  This means the labels would still be found even if they were inside a Panel (even nested Panels or other containers), for instance.  All matches are returned in the Control Array called "matches".  If no matches were found, then the Control Array would be empty and have a length of zero.  It is actually possible for more than one match to be found since you can create dynamic controls at run-time and give them a name that is already in use.  Design-time controls added through the IDE do not have this issue as Visual Studio prevents you from using a name that is already taken.

The "if" statement line ensures that a matching control was found in the form and is inside the "matches" Array, and also ensures that the type of the first control in the Array is a Label control.  The Array is of the generic Control type because multiple types could be returned; there is nothing preventing you from naming a TextBox, PictureBox, Label, Panel, etc., all the same name of "groupBox1".  So the check for a Label type is there so that the cast in the line directly below does not fail.

The first line inside the "if" block casts the matched control from the generic Control type to the Label type that it actually is.  This reference is called "lbl" and allows us to access any properties or methods that we might need that are specific to a Label control (as opposed to only the generic properties and/or methods available to a generic Control).  In this case we're only accessing the "Location()" property so casting to a Label type isn't actually necessary...I just thought this would be good to demonstrate for future purposes.

The last line in the "if" block is what actually moves your Pawn piece by setting the Location() of the pawn to the Location() of the matching Label found earlier.

With all that in mind, the code could have been shortened to simply this:

```
Control match = this.Controls.Find("label" + AllVariable.splaats1.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault();
if (match != null)
{
    picSpeler1.Location = match.Location;
}
```

but I don't think that is as easily understood by a beginner.

Comment: Thank you, it works just fine!
Can you explain it a bit?